# autoload error when using puppetlabs/chocolatey module

Tags: puppet

I am not new to puppet, but I am new to using it on Windows. Trying to configure chocolatey using the puppetlabs/chocolatey module. Initial puppet run without the module worked just fine. Then I added `include chocolatey` to the manifest, and it downloaded and installed chocolatey. So far, so good. However, then I went to add a custom source like so:

```
chocolateysource { 'mysource':
  ensure   => present,
  location => 'https://my.chocolatey.source',
  priority => 10,
}
```

Now I get the following message when running `puppet agent -t`:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> puppet agent -t
Error: Could not autoload puppet/provider/package/chocolatey: C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/cache/lib/puppet/provider/package/chocolatey.rb:280: syntax error, unexpected '.'
      pin_output&.split("\n")&.each { |pin| pin...
                  ^
C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/cache/lib/puppet/provider/package/chocolatey.rb:280: syntax error, unexpected '.'
...      pin_output&.split("\n")&.each { |pin| pins << pin.spli...
...                               ^
Error: Facter: error while resolving custom facts in C:/ProgramData\PuppetLabs\puppet\cache\lib\facter\package_provider.rb: Could not autoload puppet/provider/package/chocolatey: C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/cache/lib/puppet/provider/package/chocolatey.rb:280: syntax error, unexpected '.'
      pin_output&.split("\n")&.each { |pin| pin...
                  ^
C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/cache/lib/puppet/provider/package/chocolatey.rb:280: syntax error, unexpected '.'
...      pin_output&.split("\n")&.each { |pin| pins << pin.spli...
...                               ^
Info: Using configured environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Info: Redefining package in Puppet::Type
Error: Could not autoload puppet/type/chocolateysource: C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/cache/lib/puppet/type/chocolateysource.rb:221: syntax error, unexpected '.'
    parameter(:password)&.sensitive = true
                          ^
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Could not intern from text/pson: Could not autoload puppet/type/chocolateysource: C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/cache/lib/puppet/type/chocolateysource.rb:221: syntax error, unexpected '.'
    parameter(:password)&.sensitive = true
                          ^
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

As a non-Windows user, I feel like I'm missing something to make this work, but I'm not sure what it is. I have verified that .Net framework is installed, but not sure what else to check here. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The immediate problem is that the Ruby code for the chocolatey module, as synced to the target node, is malformed.  That shows up in the diagnostic messages in the form of all those ampersand (`&`) characters.  I don't know where those came from, but possibly there is some kind of misconfiguration related to character encoding, and / or line terminators.

Comment: Another consideration: is the version of Puppet installed on the client matched to the one installed on the server?  Client should not be more recent than server, but ideally should have the same major version number.  One major version back is usually ok for the client, but not more.

Comment: It was indeed the version. I misunderstood the labeling of the puppet agent msi files, and went with the one marked latest. Found one that was puppet 7 instead, which is the server version, and everything looks good now. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the version was the issue. I had mistakenly installed puppet 4 agent, while the server is puppet 7.